# Embeded Razor Page in a PHP site does not save cookies - Identity doesn't work

Tags: c#, php, razor-pages

I've embeded into a given PHP side a new developed Razor Page (Core 2.2).

This Razor Web App uses Identity and is hosted in MS Azure.

When calling the myWebApp.azurewebsites.net the Razor Web App works like intended - using CookiePolicy and Identity for Login, Register and so on.

After embeding this Razor Web App into a PHP web side using an  tag, the cookies for the Cookie policy of the embeded Razor Web App and also Identity doesn't look to work.

When i.e. accepting the cookie policy it will pop up when going to another page of the web-app. Further: After the Login via Identity I can see, the user was not logedin by identity. Normally the web app shows the e-Mail address of the loged in user - but it doesn't when embeded in this PHP page. Your help is very appreciated.

I've already tried to send header information of the PHP page to allow Cookies to be used, but it didn't help:

```
header('P3P:CP=HONK');
```

```
header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

I don't think this is something in the Razor Page, because it works stand-alone...

If you need some more information, please give me a hint. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the issue. It was not related to the container (the PHP file) but it was a setting missconfiguration of the services in the `Startup.cs` file.

For the missing cookie-consent banner there was an entry missing:

```
 services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
                **// This is needed for cookie-consent when embedded in a web-site(iFrame, Embed, Object)               
                options.ConsentCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;** 
            });
```

Further, the overall application cookie had also to be set for different sites:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {                
                **// Needed for usage with different domains, when embedded (iFrame, Embed, Object) 
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;** 
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                // ReturnUrlParameter requires 
                //using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
```

It's also very important to set the `service.ConfigureApplicationCookie` **AFTER** 
calling `AddIdentity` or `AddDefaultIdentity`

This worked for us. If it works for you too, I would be happy for a like :-)

Best regards, Chris